# MySQL how do I sort this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%M' ) AS MONTH,
    DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%y' ) AS YEAR,
    DEVICE,
    COUNT( * ) AS cnt
FROM users
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, DEVICE
```

I'm trying to order it by Year and Month, so something like:

- November 11
- December 11
- January 12
- ...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [`YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [`MONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) inside the `GROUP` and `ORDER BY` clauses:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%M' ) AS MONTH,
DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%y' ) AS YEAR,
DEVICE,
COUNT( * ) AS cnt
FROM users
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE), DEVICE
ORDER BY YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE)
```

You can replace `DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%y' )` with `YEAR(DATE)` as well.

Answer (score 1):

To order the things like you want, use [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%M' ) AS
MONTH , DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%y' ) AS year, DEVICE, COUNT( * ) AS cnt
FROM users
GROUP BY year, MONTH , DEVICE
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%y' ), DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%m' )
```

Comment: Would return `APRIL, AUGUST, DECEMBER, FEBRUARY...` Rather than `JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL`... OP wants chronilogical order by the looks of it.

Comment: @GarethD `DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%m' )` returns 01, 02, 03, etc.

Comment: @GarethD only `DATE_FORMAT( DATE, '%M' )` returns APRIL, AUGUST, etc.

Comment: My bad. Did not look carefully enough. Have yourself an upvote! :)